# When the product $|\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z^k)|$ tends to infinity?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I would like to know when the product

$$|\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z^k)|$$

tends to infinity?

My attempt : We have:

$$|\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z^k)|= \prod_{k=1}^n |1-z^k|$$

Since we have:

$$|1-z^k|\leq 1 +|z^k|= 1+|z|^k$$

we obtain that:
\begin{equation}
|\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z^k)|\leq 1+ \prod_{k=1}^n |z|^k
\end{equation}

Let $|z|=R$. Then:

\begin{equation}
|\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z^k)|\leq 1+ \prod_{k=1}^n R^k=1+R^{n(n+1)/2}
\end{equation}

Case 1: If $R<1$ then the product is bounded and cannot be divergent.
Case 2: If $R>1$ then the product is finite and I couldn't conclude when it diverges.

Is that correct?
My main question is to find when this product tends to infinity, even if we can consider a sequence of $z_{n_k}$ such that the product diverges

Many thank's for helping me.

Comment: Before you introduce $R$ you are claiming that $$
\prod {(1 + \left| z \right|^k )}  \le 1 + \prod {\left| z \right|^k } ,
$$
which is obviously not true in general (take $|z|=1$ for example). Also, your first inequality is in fact an equality.

Comment: I have corrected it. Do you know when the inequality your wrote is true?

Comment: I am sorry I meant $|z|>1$...

Comment: It is always the other way around. Consider, for example, $$
(1 + \left| z \right|)(1 + \left| z \right|^2 ) = 1 + \left| z \right| + \left| z \right|^2  + \left| z \right|\left| z \right|^2  \ge 1 + \left| z \right|\left| z \right|^2.
$$
Higher cases may be proved by induction.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z| >2$ then $|\prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-z^{k})|>(|z|-1)^{n} \to \infty$.

A stronger result: if $|z| >1$ choose $m$ such that $|z^{m} |>2$. Then $|\prod_{k=m}^{n} (1-z^{k})|> (|z|^{m} -1)^{n-m+1} \to \infty$. Hence $|z| >1$ is good enough.

Comment: Do we have a sufficient condition? The product tends to infinity if and only if $|z|>2$?

Comment: @Student $|z| >1$ is enough. I have edited my answer.

Comment: We are now left with the case $|z|=1$.  Supposing $z$ is not a root of unity, all factors are nonzero.  And $|1-z^n|$ is sometimes close to zero, sometimes close to $2$.

Comment: Many thank's to @KaviRamaMurthy for your helpful answer.

Comment: @GEdgarCan you please explain me more?.If $z$ is a root of unity than $z^{k_0}=1$ for some $k_0\in\{1,...,n\}$. If $z$ is not a root of unity than $z^k\neq 1$ for all $k$. How do you see that it is sometimes close to zero and sometimes close to $2$?

Comment: For non roots of unity, with norm 1, their powers are still norm 1. So they stay on the unit circle. However, their angle changes. If they start at $\theta$ then $z^n$ is at $n \theta.$ sometimes this will be close to a multiple of $2 \pi,$ sometimes close to $\pi$ more than such a multiple.